# Previous image shown after image capture

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have written code for image capture. but it shown previous picture after image capture for Moto G. It work fine for other mobile.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
 if((requestCode == ImageUtil.ClickImageId) && (resultCode == Result.Ok)) 
 {

            try 
            {
            String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id, MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data };
            String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + Constants.DESC;
            ICursor imageCursor = ContentResolver.Query(MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);
            imageCursor.MoveToFirst();
            do {
                String fullPath = imageCursor.GetString(imageCursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data));
                    if (fullPath.Contains(Constants.DCIM)) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent (this, typeof(CropImage.CropImage));
                    intent.PutExtra (Constants.IMAGE_PATH, fullPath);
                    intent.PutExtra (Constants.SCALE, true);
                    StartActivity (intent);
                    return;
                }
            }
            while (imageCursor.MoveToNext());

                } catch (Exception) {
                Toast.MakeText (this, AppMessage.UNABLE_TO_TAKE_PICTURE, ToastLength.Short).Show ();
                     }
```

}

I also tried following code it works fine but it shown small scale image. after re-size it its quality degrades.

```
                Bundle extras = data.Extras;
                bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.Get("data");
                intent = new Intent (this, typeof(CropImage.CropImage));
                intent.PutExtra("bitmap",bitmap);
                intent.PutExtra (Constants.SCALE, true);
                StartActivity (intent);
```

Comment: problem is in "fullpath", It gives me previous image path rather than last captured image path.Thank you in advance.

Comment: come on guys, Please help me.